# Screen not recomposing when state value changes - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, compose-recomposition

It is a video call screen . It needs token and channel name to work which needs to be passed to init call engine. I am storing these in a data class which is used as a mutable state.

Screen State Data class

```
@Keep
data class CallScreenState(
    val callerId: Int? = null,
    val recieverId: Int? = null,
    val chatRoom: ChatRoom.Data? = null,
    val rtcToken: AgoraTokenResponse.TokenData? = null
)
```

And in viewmodel initializing state by this code :

```
var callScreenState by mutableStateOf(CallScreenState())
```

and in viewmodel on success response of chat room and token api the state is updated with this code.

```
callScreenState = callScreenState.copy(
                                chatRoom = chatRoom.data,//from response
                                rtcToken = token.data   //from response
                            )
```

**From here it is expected to recompose the screen with new updated value of chatRoom and rtcToken.**

And in composable

```
val screenState = remember {
    viewModel.callScreenState
}
```

this screen state is used to pass values to the init engine

```
val mEngine = remember {
    initEngine(
        context,
        object : IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
            override fun onJoinChannelSuccess(channel: String?, uid: Int, elapsed: Int) {
                Timber.e("hhp-CallScreen onJoinChannelSuccess channel:$channel,uid:$uid,elapsed:$elapsed")
            }

            override fun onUserJoined(uid: Int, elapsed: Int) {
                Timber.e("hhp-CallScreen onUserJoined:$uid")
                val desiredUserList = remoteUserMap.toMutableMap()
                desiredUserList[uid] = null
                remoteUserMap = desiredUserList.toMap() as HashMap<Int, TextureView?>
            }

            override fun onUserOffline(uid: Int, reason: Int) {
                Timber.e("hhp-CallScreen onUserOffline:$uid")
                val desiredUserList = remoteUserMap.toMutableMap()
                desiredUserList.remove(uid)
                remoteUserMap = desiredUserList.toMap() as HashMap<Int, TextureView?>
            }

            override fun onNetworkQuality(uid: Int, txQuality: Int, rxQuality: Int) {
                Timber.e("hhp-CallScreen onNetworkQuality $uid $txQuality $rxQuality")

            }
        },
        screenState.chatRoom?.channelName ?: "",  //Not recomposing when value changes in viewmodel
        viewModel.userRole,
        token = screenState.rtcToken?.token ?: "" //Not recomposing when value changes in viewmodel
    )
}
```

This is the initEngine function creation

```
fun initEngine(
    current: Context,
    eventHandler: IRtcEngineEventHandler,
    channelName: String,
    userRole: String,
    token: String
): RtcEngine =
    RtcEngine.create(current, BuildConfig.AGORA_APPID, eventHandler).apply {
        enableVideo()
        setChannelProfile(1)
        if (userRole == "Broadcaster") {
            setClientRole(1)
        } else {
            setClientRole(0)
        }
        //Expected to be recomposed when screen state value updated with new values
        joinChannel(token, channelName, "", 0)
    }
```

I understand at the very beginging, channel name and token inside the screen state is empty that is before the api call . Once api for getting token and chat room gives succes , the screen state updated from viewmodel and i expect the initEngine fun to be called again as it should recompose. But it is not. Am I Missing something ? How to make it recompose whenver the channelname value inside screen sctate changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand your entire use-case but have you tried specifying a `key` to your `remember`?

> How to make it recompose whenver the channelname value inside screen
> sctate changes?

You can try either of these, though I'm not sure if they would solve your problem, but when you supply a `key` to `remember` and it changes, it will `re-calculate`, assuming the `channelName` that has been used by `remember's` previous calculation will be different on the next `re-composition`.

This,

```
val screenState = remember(key1 = channelname) {
    viewModel.callScreenState
}
```

or this

```
val mEngine = remember(key1 = channelname) { ... }
```

Comment: Perfect! It solved the problem i was missing the key inside remember. Thanks alot @z.y

Comment: I tried using keys with `remember`, but it didn't help, it still gives me the old state. I fixed the problem by not using `remember` at all. If you can even consider that fixing the problem.